# java visualvm jdbc profiler: does it capture the final sql statements that are actually executed by the DB?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, visualvm, jvisualvm

[image]

I am using JVisualVm's jdbc profiler to monitor my local java program.

It would capture something like this:

`select * from reservation v where v.name like '%'%'`

If you try to run this in pgadmin, it would throw error:

[image]

For PgAdmin to run it, we have to escape the single quote in the string:

`select * from reservation where name like '%''%'`

Basically we need to change ' to '' so that the string the sql does not get cut off into 2 pieces.

My question is: is visual vm's jdbc profiler able to capture the final sql statement that gets executed by the DB?

Comment: Unlikely, because there is nothing in the JDBC API that allows you to capture what the driver implementation sends to the server.